# Rails self-referential has_many through with custom naming of join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, relational-database, has-many, self-reference

I have some troubles wrapping my head around the following situation..

I am trying to create a tree structure, where I will be able to give custom names to connections between nodes..

So I want to have Node and Relation models. Each

```
Node 
 has_many :relations
```

Each

```
Relation 
 has_many :nodes
```

Node can be either a parent or a child.. So far everything was easy and there are tons of examples that show how to make a self-referential has_many table... The problem is that I want  to be able to give names to relations, so that I can do something like:

```
relation1 = node1.relations.create(:name => "relation_name", :child => node2)
```

and in result get something like:

```
relation1.name == "relation_name"
relation1.parent == node1
relation1.child == node2
```

All the creations are happening within the model, this activity is not really exposed to user, if that matters.
Thanks!

EDIT2: 
Here is how it works now:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sentence

  has_one :parent_relation, :foreign_key => "child_id", :class_name => "Relation"
  has_many :child_relations, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => "Relation"

  has_one :parent, :through => :parent_relation
  has_many :children,  :through => :child_relations, :source => :child

  has_many :relations, :foreign_key => "child_id"
  has_many :relations, :foreign_key => "parent_id"

class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :videos, :as => :videoable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :phrases, :through => :videos

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Node"#, :inverse_of => :parent_relation
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "Node"#, :inverse_of => :child_relation
```

Comment: So a `relation` can only have one `parent` and one `child`?  Or can it have multiple of each?

Comment: You keep changing your question haha, I'm going to try and just answer the original question to the best of my ability. I think that it will kinda help you solve your other questions by making your code a little more understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what you're talking about is more like a [Joins Model](http://label-Association+Join+Models) than a Self-Reference.

*Note: I changed your `relation` association 'labels' because I was having a hard time with your naming, so you don't have to change your 'labels' that was just for me.*

So for your `Node` class you could do something like this

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one  :parent_relation, :foreign_key => "child_id",
                              :class_name => "Relation"
   has_many :child_relations, :foreign_key => "parent_id", 
                              :class_name => "Relation"

   has_one  :parent, :through => :parent_relation
   has_many :children, :through => :child_relations, :source => :child
end
```

Then for your `Relation` class you could something like

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Node", :inverse_of => :parent_relation
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "Node", :inverse_of => :child_relations
end
```

The `:inverse_of` option should let you build let you build a `Node` based off the `parent` and `children` associations from your `Node` instances, this is just a caveat from the **magic** with `:through` relationships. (Documentation for this is at the bottom of the [Joins Model](http://label-Association+Join+Models) section.)

I don't fully understand your association structure, but I think this should model it correctly. Lemme know if there are any problems though.

*Side Note: Since `Relation` is a constant set in the `ActiveRecord` module you might consider changing it to something like `NodeRelationship`. I don't think it will interfere with your program, but it definitively caused some trouble for my thought process.*

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Although I had to comment out the :inverse_of =>  part.. it was giving error otherwise. I will edit the question so it reflects the current setup

Comment: The error is:  Could not find the inverse association for child

Comment: err sorry it should be `child_relations`